# PHP | From filter to search?

Tags: php, search, web

I wanted to make a PHP search, but my code works like an filter.
How can I change/fix it?

```html
<div class="block-header">
 
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="spieler" placeholder="...">
 <button class="los" name="search" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Suche</button>
     
 <h2>
 
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
 <tr>
     <td><a style="font-weight:none;">Name:</a> <?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
     <td>| <a style="font-weight:none;">Kills:</a> <?php echo $row['Kills'];?></td>
     <td>| <a style="font-weight:none;">Deaths:</a> <?php echo $row['Deaths'];?><br></td>
 </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
 </h2>
 </form>
      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the rest of the code, with the Connection.

```html
<?php include 'util/db.php'; 

    if(isset($_GET['search']))
    {
        $spieler = $_GET['spieler'];
        // search in all table columns
        // using concat mysql function
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `skypvp` WHERE CONCAT(`name`) LIKE '%".$spieler."%'";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
        
    }
     else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `skypvp`";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

    // function to connect and execute the query
    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }
    ?>
```